# Ringer Mode Vibrate no Android

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se é possível programaticamente chamar setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) sem o dispositivo vibrar no momento em que o método é chamado?

O Android tem um comportamento padrão quando configuramos o sound mode: vibrar quando selecionamos o modo RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE, diretamente no dispositivo. E esse comportamento também se repete quando feito via código.

Quando abro a app, o sound mode do dispositivo deve ser colocado para RINGER_MODE_NORMAL. Mas quando fecho, o estado anterior deve ser restaurado. Ao restaurar o estado RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE o telefone vibra.

Gostaria que ele não vibrasse ao configurar RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE. Há alguma forma de inibir essa vibração?

Answer (score 1):

Chama o método startVibrate dentro do método que você espera vibrar...

```
private void metodoQueVibra(){
  startVibrate();
}

public void startVibrate() {
  long pattern[] = { 0, 100, 200, 300, 400 };
  vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
}
```

Referencia:

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/vibrate-android-device-with-example.html#.U_4eS_ldXp4